# Inverse of a 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

I have shown that $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is invertible for all $x\neq 0, y \neq 0$, but I need to find the inverse function. The Jacobi Matrix of the inverse is $$\begin{bmatrix} 
     \frac{x}{2(x^2+y^2)} &  \frac{y}{2(x^2+y^2)}\\
    \frac{-y}{2(x^2+y^2)} & \frac{x}{2(x^2+y^2)} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to integrate the first and second component in order to find the x component and y component of my inverse function, but it didn't work out, can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is *not* invertible, since it is not injective. Note that $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$.

Comment: We could then consider only the positive x and y or the negative x and y in a neighborhood that does not include 0, and it would be invertible

Comment: Yes, of course. If that's you want, just solve the equation $f(x,y)=(a,b)$. It's not hard. You'll get$$x=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2}\text{ and }y=\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2}.$$